# How to escape underscores in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, wildcard

When searching for underscores in Postgresql, literal use of the character `_` doesn't work. For example, if you wanted to search all your tables for any columns that ended in `_by`, for something like change log or activity information, e.g. `updated_by`, `reviewed_by`, etc., the following query almost works:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name LIKE '%_by'
```

It basically ignores the underscore completely and returns as if you'd searched for `LIKE '%by'`. This may not be a problem in all cases, but it has the potential to be one. How to search for underscores?

Comment: `%` and `_` are THE wildcard characters for `like` matching. `%` = zero-or-more, `_` = any one single character.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to use a backslash to escape the underscore. Change the example query to the following:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name LIKE '%\_by'
```

Comment: I had to do `... like E'%\\_by'` (using psql on the command line, PostgreSQL 8.4.20)

Comment: How to find on this case: SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name LIKE '%name_abc'

Comment: @BradCupit: This is strange, I had to do `E'%\_by'` in PostgreSQL 9.5.

Answer (score 13):

Just ran into the same issue and the single backslash wasn't working as well. I found this documentation on the PostgreSQL community and it worked:

> The correct way is to escape the underscore with a backslash. You
>   actually have to write two backslashes in your query:
>
> select * from
>   foo where bar like '%\\_baz'
>
> The first backslash quotes the second one for the query parser, so
>   that what ends up inside the system is %\_baz, and then the LIKE
>   function knows what to do with that.

Therefore use something like this:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name LIKE '%\\_by'
```

Source Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10965.962991238%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 0):

Just a point of pedantry on one aspect of your question:

```
It basically ignores the underscore completely and returns as if you'd searched for LIKE '%by'.
```

This isn't correct. What's happening here is that underscore is another wildcard character supported by postgres' pattern matching. From: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

```
An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more characters.
```

i.e if you've ever used DOS wildcards, the underscore is analgous to the `?` DOS wildcard, matching any character, but exactly one character, whereas the `%` in postgres matches 0 or more characters - i.e `%` matches any string including an empty string, but `_` matches any string which is exactly one character long.

Thus, `WHERE column_name LIKE '%_by'` isn't quite the same as `WHERE column_name like '%by'`, since the string `by` does not match the first but does match the second (it has 0 characters before the `by` and therefore does not match the underscore wildcard)