# Regex in PostgreSQL doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

1. `ABCD9876S__9999.A001`
2. `ABCD9876S__9999.A002`

   - Always starts with ABCD
   - Followed by a mix of digits and alphabets
   - Followed by two underscores __
   - Followed by 9999.A00 1 or 2

I want to catch the above two strings using reg ex

I have :

```
ABCD.*9999\.A00[12]
```

This doesn't work in Postgres. How do I convert this? Is there an online tool?

Comment: Try `ABCD[a-zA-Z0-9]+__9999\.A00[12]`

Comment: Try using this regex `^ABCD[a-zA-Z0-9]+__9999\.A00[12]$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/adbsts/1)

Comment: Does it work like this? https://rextester.com/DRAB22299

Comment: It doesn't work.. As soon as I do the 9999 it fails. Doesn't error out but doesnt pull the data. I am using "where Name ~ ('ABCD[0-9a-zA-Z].*') " which works. But finally I want to be able to choose between 1 and 2 meaning A001 or A002

Comment: For underscore.. I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084864/how-to-escape-underscores-in-postgresql

Comment: I think the tilde `~` returns a boolean. See  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html Try using REGEXP_MATCHES from the demo.

Comment: REGEXP_MATCHES does not work with where clause. Not sure how to use this with where or how to make the select work..

Comment: Can I do the REGEXP_MATCHES on a  column?

Comment: @Ram Do you mean like this? https://rextester.com/VQUNHP73524

Comment: Yes. It worked! Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the character ranges that you want to allow using a character class and add the double undescore you want to be part of the match.

```
ABCD[a-zA-Z0-9]+__9999\.A00[12]
```

If the match should be from the start of the string use anchors `^` and `$`

See a postgre sql [demo 1](https://rextester.com/UZO81046) | [demo 2](https://rextester.com/FGEL2721) using [regexp_matches](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE)