# SOLVED: How to remove Key duplication error Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

### **Stack**

PostgresQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 
Django 3.0 with DRF

### **Problem**

I am trying to build a model with the below desired models.py. But I used the pythonic way to name variables, but I now realize that PostgreSQL ignores the "_", thus "region" and "region_number" appear to be the same key.

**region_number** should be **regionNumber**

My question is how to I correct this?

What I have tried:

1. Simply correcting the model element names and migrating - error is still there
2. Migrating back to before I applied this migration
3. Dropping the Index in SQL; returns "cannot drop index XXX_Index because constraint XXX_Index on table (my_table_name) requires it

### **CURRENT models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class DataInput(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    region_number = models.IntegerField()
```

### **Error python manage.py migrate**

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: could not create unique index "Region and Number"
DETAIL:  Key (region, region_number)=(US EAST, 1) is duplicated.
```

### **DESIRED models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class DataInput(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    regionNumber = models.IntegerField()
```

### Thanks so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084864/how-to-escape-underscores-in-postgresql
See if this solves your problem.

Comment: SOLVED: There was a test DataInput row that I forgot about. So the error had nothing to do with the name of the column, just the fact that values --that were supposed to be unique--were duplicated.